# Converting empty string into null

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have a form that POST value keeps coming as "" empty string into a unique SQL field. 
It has to be unique as the field is optional but jet it can not have 2 same values. The unique value does allow null multiple values.
I don't even want to say what I tried to do, I'm trying to fix this for last few days. 
Closest that I got is putting '$OIB'=IF('$OIB'='',NULL,'$OIB' into NSERT INTO statement, then i get null values into a database but for some reason when the number is entered into OIB form field it puts number 1 into a database...

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT OIB, NAZIV FROM STRANKEP WHERE OIB = '$OIB' OR NAZIV = '$NAZIV'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
     // row not found, do stuff...
     $sql = "INSERT INTO STRANKEP (NAZIV, OIB, EMAIL, ADRESA, TELEFON) VALUES ('$NAZIV', CASE WHEN '$OIB' = '' THEN 'NULL', '$EMAIL', '$ADRESA', '$TELEFON')";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

This solution gets me null but not the real $OIB when entered into form, it just puts number 1.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT OIB, NAZIV FROM STRANKEP WHERE OIB = '$OIB' OR NAZIV = '$NAZIV'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
     // row not found, do stuff...
     $sql = "INSERT INTO STRANKEP (NAZIV, OIB, EMAIL, ADRESA, TELEFON) VALUES ('$NAZIV', '$OIB'=IF('$OIB'='',NULL,'$OIB'), '$EMAIL', '$ADRESA', '$TELEFON')";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Please reap up on Sql injection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Not using prepared statements is completely unacceptable coding.

Comment: I'm a noob, sorry, also this is only for the local networks and few people using the database. But I will make changes.

Comment: Why not check for such values and convert them to `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use also IF Clause

Like so

```
INSERT INTO STRANKEP (NAZIV, OIB, EMAIL, ADRESA, TELEFON) VALUES 
('$NAZIV', IF('$OIB' = '', NULL,'$OIB'), '$EMAIL', '$ADRESA', '$TELEFON');
```

But as mentioned in my comment use prepared statements like in PDO https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared

Comment: Tried that,it stores NULL as a text and not as real null.

Comment: i edited my answer remove simply the ticks around NULL

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
CASE '$OIB' WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE '$OIB' END
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `nullif()`.  It is a built-in standard function to do exactly this:

```
nullif(?, '')
```

Note:  Do not munge queries with constant values.  That makes the code subject to SQL injection attacks.  And it can introduce very hard-to-debug errors.  Use parameters!